# c++ - Is there a way to auto-cast values when assigning them to references`?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is some way that C++ autocasts values that I want to assign to a reference.

```
class X{
public:
    X(int x){
    }
};

int main(){
    X x = 5;        //works
    X& y = 6;       //doesn't work
    X& z = (X)7;    //works
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, assigning 6 to the reference y does not work without casting it before. Is there something I can add in the definition of the class X to make this work without the casting, so that the non-working line would work?

Basically I want to achieve that, for example a function like this:

```
void doSomething(X& x){
    //...
}
```

Could be called like this after that:

```
doSomething(7);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would  you need a reference to the number 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lvalue references to non-`const` can only bind to lvalues. `6` is a prvalue, so it cannot bind to `y`. What you are doing in this line:

```
X& z = (X)7;
```

Is basically equivalent to this:

```
X& z = X(7);
```

On the right side, it creates a temporary of type `X`, and then binds it to an lvalue reference. In C++, this is illegal - temporaries are rvalues. Your compiler probably allows doing so as a (not very clever) documented extension.

Avoid writing that kind of code. This, on the other hand, is legal:

```
X const& z = 6;
```

And the lifetime of the temporary bound to `z` will be prolonged to match the lifetime of the `z` reference itself (12.2/5). So you should write your function this way:

```
void doSomething(X const& x)
//                 ^^^^^
{
    //...
}
```

lvalue references to `const` *can* bind to rvalues (including temporaries). Therefore, the following call would be legal:

```
doSomething(7)
```

And it would construct a temporary of type `X` by providing `7` as the constructor's argument, then binding the function parameter `x` to that temporary.

Comment: What I actually don't understand is, why would one not ever write const before the '&'? Has it any drawbacks? Ok, I wouldn't use it for variables in functions because I cant change them, but in functions, noone changes the parameter variables, so...

Comment: @VanCoding: Well, you cannot modify an object through a reference to `const`

Comment: @VanCoding: I do not think it is true that "*in functions, noone changes the parameter variable*". It is pretty common to have references to non-`const` as function parameters

Comment: Ah, I see what the drawback is now :) Thank you :)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, that was meant to be a general piece of information not specifically related to the example that preceded it - but I understand this is not really clear. I will edit, thank you