# implicit cast not working when passing by reference

Tags: c++

```
union A {
    public:
    B b;
    inline operator B() const {
        return b;
    }
}
void doSomething(B& b){};
A a;
doSomething(a);
```

Getting "no matching function for call to" error using code similar to above. Can you not implicilty cast to reference like this?

Work around?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16109100/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3895647/560648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call `doSomething(a)`, `a` is converted to an rvalue of type `B` using the conversion operator (which returns by value, hence the new temporary object).

Since rvalues can only be used as non-const reference or value parameters, you can't call `doSomething` with an rvalue.

Either declare `doSomething` to take its argument by const reference, by value, or by rvalue-reference. You could also make `operator B` return a reference to the `b` member if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The cast-operator returns `b` *by value*, and using that result when calling the `doSomething` function would create a *temporary* value, and you simply can't have references to temporary values because of their temporary nature.

Either change `doSomething` to receive its argument by value, or by *`const`* reference (which can bind to a temporary value), or possibly a rvalue-reference (using the `&&` syntax in the argument declaration), or of course make a cast-operator that returns a reference.